Minicom spamming the output in reading serial port
When I'm reading the output of a serial-usb converter using minicom 2.9 (let's say /dev/ttyUSB0), from time to time the output of minicom gets spammed with ...Minicom2.9Minicom2.9Minicom2.9... continuously. And the main output is not readable anymore. Even if I close the port and open it again, this problem won't go away.
I tried this with different usb-serial converters and it did happen with all of them.
The only way that I found for "cleaning up" the output is to close the port on minocom, open-close it using screen, and again open it in minicom.
The reason why I'm not using gnu-screen instead of minicom is the ability to timestamp every printed line in minicom.
Can anybody help me solve this issue?
